# Extensions in the category $F\text{-Isoc}(X)$

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, tannakian-category, crystals

Let $X$ be a smooth affine scheme over a finite field $k$, let $W(k)$ denote its Witt ring, and by $K$ its fraction field.

Let $F\text{-Isoc}(X/K)$ denote the category of convergent $F$-isocrystals on $X$. The forgetful functor which forgets the Frobenius structure offers a functor from $F\text{-Isoc}(X/K)$ to $VIC(X_K)$, which is the category of vector bundles with an integrable connection on a smooth lift of $X$, defined over $K$, denoted $X_K$.

By abuse of notations, denote by $\mathcal{E}$ both an isocrystal and its underlying vector bundle. What can be said about the extension group $\operatorname{Ext}_1(\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2)$ in both categories, are they the same?